# Prompt for choice. Re-prompt if option is invalid

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering how to re-prompt if someone typos or enters something other than yes/no
Would it have to be a created as a prompting function or is there an easier way?

```
$Continue = Read-Host -Prompt "Continue? Yes/No"
Switch($Continue){
    'Yes' { Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Moving on..." }
    'No' {Write-host "...GoodBye" 
            Exit
         }
    default { #HOW TO RE-PROMPT USER FOR YES/No?
        }
}
```

Comment: For example enclose your code in a `do {...} While ($Continue -notmatch '^(Yes|No)$')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a While loop which a check variable. If **Yes** is typed then `$Check` will equal `$true` exiting the loop. Else it will stay false and rerun the loop again.

```
$Check = $false
while($Check -eq $false){
    Switch(Read-Host -Prompt "Continue? Yes/No"){
        'Yes' {
            Write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Moving on..."
            $Check = $true
        }
        'No' {
            Write-host "...GoodBye" 
            return
        }
    }
}
```